# CURL statement to Python Requests

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I am trying to convert a CURL statement to python requests code and no response from server

CURL command I have is

```
curl --user user:pass --anyauth --user-agent 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)' -F "archive=" -F "mysubmit=Screenshot" -F "passwd=" 172.xx.xx.xx/plug
```

When I run above command, I am getting desired result. Now I am trying to convert this CURL command into Python Requests lib code. Took reference from Requests lib documentation and Stackoverflow questions on same topic

This is what I am trying

```
>>> import requests
>>> from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
>>> data = {'archive': '', 'mysubmit': 'Screenshot'}
>>> headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
>>> resp = requests.post('http://172.18.5.57/plugin_inspect',auth=HTTPDigestAuth('rokudev','developer'), headers=headers, data=data)
```

When I post the request.post, I am not getting any response from server. I am doing something wrong and I am not able to figure out what

Any suggestions on what needs to be changed?

Thanks

Comment: What do you get if you print `r.status_code` and `r.content` ? ( assuming that you missed a line, and `r` is the request obj )

Comment: I have updated the statements. I am not getting back any response from server and just waiting for response